# Deleting the cursor object

Tags: python, arcpy, cursor

Can someone explain why you need to delete the cursor objects and the iterator when you use for example:

```
arcpy.UpdateCursor(blah)
```

I've checked the [esri docs](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v00000064000000) and there doesn't seem to be an explanation there, but the object is shown to be deleted at the end of both example scripts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to delete the object in order to release any locks the `UpdateCursor` has taken out.

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that in the commented code. Cheers.

Comment: For those that are interested if you use the code: "with arcpy.UpdateCursor(blah) as cursor" this will 'guarantee close and release of database locks and reset iteration' as stipulated in the relevant ESRI documentation.